# Running multiple executions simultaneously

Tags: powershell

I am trying to put together a "convenience" script.  It's advanced to the point where I actually need it to execute multiple things at once.

Basically, I need it to launch two development web servers in separate Command Prompt windows.  Is that something that can be done from a PowerShell script?  If so, how?

I'm using whatever PowerShell version that comes with Windows 10.

```cs
$ep = Get-ExecutionPolicy

if ($ep -eq 'RemoteSigned') {
    $root = "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\_code_projects\"
    $whichserver = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the name of the project you'll be working on"
    $test = "y" # Read-Host -Prompt 'Would you like to activate the python environment? y/n'
    $activatestr = ($root + "env\Scripts\Activate.ps1")
    $path = ($root + "django_projects\" + $whichserver + "\")
    $runserverstr = ($path + "\manage.py")

    if ($test -eq 'y') {
        & $activatestr
    }

    $test = Read-Host -Prompt 'Would you like to run the ATOM IDE? y/n'
    if ($test -eq 'y') {
        atom $path
    }

    #$test = Read-Host -Prompt 'Would you like to cd into the project root directory? y/n'
    if ($test -eq 'y') {
        cd $path
    }

    $test = Read-Host -Prompt 'Would you like to run the  dev servers? y/n'
    # Here, I would like to open command prompt either in the root of the react app, or
    # cd into it, then start it. Then I would like to launch the django dev server.
    if ($test -eq 'y') {
        cd $path + $whichserver + "_react_main"
        cmd.exe /C npm start
        cd ..
        cmd.exe /C python.exe $runserverstr runserver
    }
```

Comment: Did you try just `Start-Process`? It doesn't wait for the called process to return - like `Start-Process -FilePath "npm" -ArgumentList "start" -WorkingDirectory $pwd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-3.0) (or its alias `start`):

```
Start-Process 'python.exe' -ArgumentList $runserverstr, 'runserver'
```

Another option would be to launch the server processes as [background jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288.aspx):

```
$job = Start-Job {
    & 'python.exe' $runserverstr 'runserver'
}
```

The latter would run the processes in the background, so their output isn't displayed in the console, but you can fetch it via [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job?view=powershell-3.0):

```
Receive-Job -Job $job
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that this - in the special case of the OP's script will work with `python.exe` but may not work with `node` as no absolute path is provided in the arguments and `start` needs a package definition.

Comment: I was assuming that it should work since the original code had no paths as well and supposedly worked. Still, valid point.

Comment: This is correct for `Start-Process`, as it starts in `$pwd`, but not for `Start-Job`. When received, `Start-Job {cmd /C echo %cd%}` will return another path than `Start-Process "cmd" -ArgumentList "/C", "echo %cd%&pause"` if not started from user's home

Comment: It looks like your response using Start-Process was exactly what I need.  I tested using  `Start-Process 'python' -ArgumentList './manage.py', 'runserver'` from within the directory.